# Attach text to center of image only using grid template

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a background image which has on top another div containing some elements.
I success to add the `white-container` on top of the background div using grid-template-area.
I try to do the same thing only using grid and not position. But text `hello world` doesn't go on top of love icon using grid area `love-svg`.
I think perhaps because img tag has no closed tag, but can't find a way to solve this problem.

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
    <img src="/images/site/trust_pilot_bg_mb.jpg" >
    <div class="white-container">
        <div class="love-section">
            <img class="love-ico" src="/images/site/love_svg_icon.svg"><h2 class="hello">Hello world</h2> </img>
            
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

SCSS

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    grid-template-areas: "content-wrapper";

    &>* {
        grid-area: content-wrapper;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
    }


    .love-section
    {
        display: grid;
        background-color: white;
        top: 40px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .love-ico {
        width: 100px;  
        grid-template-areas: "love-svg";
    }

    .hello {
        color: red;
        grid-area: love-svg;
    }
}
```

In blue this is what I want to achieve. Please note that I want the text to be on top of the love logo but allow it to be bigger than it.

[image: In blue this in what I want to achieve]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use grid to do that, you'll need to play with the align-self, and justify-self for the grid-item.

Now there are several ways to do that with grid, the way you are using it is not the simplest.

I'm proposing just one here:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  gap: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 8 / 8;
}

#div1 img,
#div2 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

#div2 {
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 6 / 6;
}

#div3 {
  grid-area: 4 / 4 / 5 / 5;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="div1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <img class="love-ico" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <h2>Hello world</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I don't know if it's mandatory for you to use grid, otherwise the old technic of relative, absolute works too:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/300/200");
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#container h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img class="love-ico" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
  <h2>Hello world</h2>
</div>
```